# Extend $f\in C^\infty(0,\infty)$ to a $C^\infty$ function on $\mathbb R$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f^{(k)}(x)=c_k$

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Let $f\in C^\infty(0,\infty)$ and assume that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f^{(k)}(x)=c_k$ exist and finite for each $k=0,1,2\cdots$. Show that $f$ can be extended to a $C^\infty$ function on $\mathbb R$.

One given hint is: define $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\frac{x^k}{k!}\chi(\epsilon_k^{-1}x)$ with a good smooth function $\chi$ and pick right $\{\epsilon_k\}$.

Take $\chi\in C^\infty_c([-1,1])$ and $\chi=1$ on $(-1/2,1/2)$. so we can pick $\epsilon_k$ to make $g$ is well-defined and let $g=f$ on $(0,\infty)$. And we can show that $g^{(k)}(0)=c_k$ for all $k$, but I have difficulty to show $\lim_{x\to 0^-}g^{(k)}(x)=c_k$.

To start this, I think one can fix $x\in(2^{-i},2^{-i+1})$, then the nontrivial part is $-1<\epsilon_k^{-1}x<-
\frac{1}{2}$. Any idea to finish this end?

Comment: See [Borel’s lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma).

Comment: I find this confusing: "And we can show that $g^{(k)}(0)=c_k$ for all $k$". If you can prove that, then you've proven that $g$ is infinitely differentiable at $0$, which automatically implies that $g^{(k)}$ is continuous at $0$ for all $k$. Hence $\lim_{x\to 0}g^{(k)}(x)=g^{(k)}(0) = c_k$.

Comment: But I think we still need to show the left limit exist by the definition of continuous.